# `import re` вызывает ошибку: "AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'"

Tags: python

При компиляции Python, компилятор ссылается на файл re.py который тот в свою очередь ссылается на enum.py

При обработке re.py в консоль выходит ошибка

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "string", line 1, in "module"
>
> File "C:\Users\Gr4Y\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python3632\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 39, in 
>   "module"
>
> import re
>
> File "C:\Users\Gr4Y\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\re.py", line >143, in "module"
>
> class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
>
> AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'

Данная ошибка была вызвана когда я используя программу для сборки .py в .exe  .
Программа Auto Py To Exe Master

https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe

Answer (score 0):

Требуется удалить `enum34`.

Введите в терминале (или консоли):

```
pip uninstall enum34
```